# Horizontal alignment of multi-level nested list elements without a table (like TreeView/TreeList)

Tags: html, css, treeview, treelist

I want to display somewhat resembling a tabular tree view with expandable rows and several aligned columns, i.e something like this:

[image: What I want to get]

I'd like to lay it out naturally, as a nested list of lists, i.e. something like:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="first">usr</span>
        <span class="second">root</span>
        <span class="third">drwxr-xr-x</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span class="first">bin</span>
                <span class="second">root</span>
                <span class="third">drwxr-xr-x</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <span class="first">which → /bin/which</span>
                        <span class="second">root</span>
                        <span class="third">lrwxrwxrwx</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

While it's generally to lay out such loosely tabular data with elements that have fixed `width` and `display: inline-block`, alas, it obviously doesn't work when start of the row is misaligned due to different nesting levels.

My current try is available at http://jsfiddle.net/2Lqmx9kt/ - and, as you can see, all the columns are misaligned.

I could only come up with 2 solutions, both are fairly ugly:

1. Replace everything with a table, ultimately losing nested DOM structure.
2. Rely on ugly tricks like

   ```
   ul > li > span.first {
       // full width
   }
   ul > li > ul > li > span.first {
       // remove one level of width
   }
   ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > span {
       // remove two levels of width
   }
   ```

Is there any good way to lay it out without major changes in DOM, without Javascript, with some clever CSS trick?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with negative margins on the nested elements' second spans:

```
ul ul li .second {
    margin-left: -2.5em;
}

ul ul ul li .second {
    margin-left: -5em;
}
```

Edited your fiddle too to represent the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/2Lqmx9kt/1/

I'm curious, though. Why do you want to do it like this, when there's a plethora of solutions that do this via jQuery/Javascript data handling, i.e. Telerik Kendo UI's [TreeList](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/index)? Why the need for HTML nesting?

Comment: That's basically the same as specifying width for every level of nesting - even worse in some aspects, i.e. cell contents overflowing horizontally wouldn't get wrapped properly. You're probably right, in real world I'll either resort to HTML table or stuff like Kendo UI. This question is more of theoretical nature to understand whether it's possible to lay it out with normal CSS nowadays.

Comment: You are correct. This solution would require a similar hack with margin-right or padding-right to correct overflowing in the first span. Then again, wrapping in an 'li' is bound to be problematic anyway.